# Set NSStatusBar title from other class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Im trying to change the title in my NSStatusBar from a different class, my preferences class.

In my ManagerClass.m & .h I have declared

```
- (NSStatusItem *)statusItem { return statusItem; }
```

I then import my ManagerClass.h in my preferences.m

then inside preferences.m I try to execute:

```
ManagerClass *someInstanceToIt = [[ManagerClass alloc] init]; 
[(NSStatusItem *)[someInstanceToIt statusItem] setTitle:@"New Title"];
```

But it seems that statusItem is never being passed to the preferences.m file, if i do a test with an if i can see that statusItem is empty.

Any ideas? I'm completely stuck

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance when using `[[ManagerClass alloc] init]`. You probably want an object you created previously, and not a new object.

There are to methods to solve your problem:
- The first solution is passing the created `ManagerClass` instance and pass that to the preference controller. But in this case you'll have to constantly keep that `ManagerClass` instance in a variable so you don't loose it.
- Another method is implementing a singleton design. This means you'll have the option to have one shared object in your whole application. An example can be found below:

```
@implementation aClass
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)sharedInstance { // note the + for a class method
    static id shared = nil;
    if(shared == nil) {
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return shared;
}
@end
```

Now you can call this code to receive the same object every time you call it:

```
aClass *sharedObject = [aClass sharedInstance];
```

Hope it helps,
ief2

Answer (score 0):

First, `someInstanceToIt` should be an instance variable, so that you can own this instance as long as you need the status item.

Second, make sure you implement `-[ManagerClass init]` to create the NSStatusItem and store it in the ManagerClass instance's `statusItem` instance variable. `statusItem` contains `nil` until that happens.

Third, “ManagerClass” is not a very good name for a class. Note how I had to say “the ManagerClass instance” above. I suggest “StatusItemManager” instead; with that change, I could have said “the StatusItemManager's instance variable”.